# .less Bundle in Styles.Render Not Working in .aspx

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, .aspxauth

I am working on a project that uses a .aspx page and I am not able to reference the Styles.Render correctly in the BundleConfig. I am using the bundle transformer and dotless in the bundle config and this is working just fine in my normal HTML header, however in the .aspx page it is not understanding the .less page correctly. I am receiving this error in the console `Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://localhost:58743/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fContent%2fless%2fbootstrap.less"`.